# Solve quadractic inequality with two variables

Tags: inequality

> $x^2-2ax+a \geq 0$

I've to find the values for $a$ how should a proceed in this situation? I already know that the answer is $0\leq a \leq 1$ But i couldn't find a way to reach that conclusion. Any idea?

Comment: You can use the discriminant to determine when the curve doesn't cross the $x$ axis. Since the parabola opens upward, all values must be non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

> Solve for $x$ and $a$ : $x^2 - 2ax + a \geq 0.$

Since $(x - a)^2 = x^2 - 2ax + a^2$, 
the problem may be re-expressed as

$$(x - a)^2 + (a - a^2) \geq 0 \iff (x - a)^2 \geq (a^2 - a) = a(a-1). \tag1 $$

(1) above may be attacked by considering whether

- $0 \leq a \leq 1.$
- $1 < a.$
- $a < 0.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1}~: ~~0 \leq a \leq 1}$

Then, $(a^2 - a) = a(a-1)$ is always *non-positive*
and $(x - a)^2$, being a square, is always non-negative, 
so any value of $x$ will satisfy (1) above, in Case 1.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2}~: ~~1 < a}$

Then, $(a^2 - a) = a(a-1)$ is always positive. 
This allows you to assume that $\sqrt{a^2 - a}$ 
is a real number.

In general, the equation $[f(x)]^2 \geq r ~: ~r \in \Bbb{R^+}$ is solved by either

- $f(x) \geq \sqrt{r}$
- or $f(x) \leq -\sqrt{r}$.

So, in Case 2, (1) above will be solved by:

- $(x - a) \geq \sqrt{a^2 - a} \iff x \geq a + \sqrt{a^2 - a}$
- or $(x - a) \leq -\sqrt{a^2 - a} \iff x \leq a - \sqrt{a^2 - a}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3}~: ~~a < 0}$

The easiest way to analyze Case 3 is to set $b = (-a) \implies b > 0.$

Then (1) above may be re-expressed as

$$(x + b)^2 \geq b^2 + b \tag2 $$

where you know that the RHS of (2) above is positive.

Therefore, (2) above may be re-expressed as

$$(x + b) \geq \sqrt{b^2 + b}.$$

Very similar to the analysis in Case 2, this will have solutions of

- $x \geq (-b) + \sqrt{b^2 + b}.$
- or $x \leq (-b) - \sqrt{b^2 + b}.$

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
x^2-2ax+a=(x-a)^2+a-a^2,
$$
you have $x^2-2ax+a\ge0$ for every $x$ if and only if $a-a^2\ge0$. And this occurs if and only if $a\in[0,1]$.

Comment: the thing is that i don't get how you came to that conclusion, could you please elaborate more your example?

Comment: If $a-a^2\ge0$, then, since we always have $(x-a)^2\ge0$, we always have $(x-a)^2+a-a^2\ge0$. On the other hand, if $a-a^2<0$, then it is false that we always have $(x-a)^2+a-a^2\ge0$, since $(x-a)^2+a-a^2=a-a^2<0$ when $x=a$.